# Validate phone number on blur using pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I have a form and on blur I would like to check if the phone number is in the right format, but it seems to fail every time.

```js
$('.form-control').blur(function(){                    
    if(!this.validity.valid){                        
        $(this).addClass('emptyField');

    }
    else{
        $(this).removeClass('emptyField');
    }
})
```

```css
.emptyField { background:red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}" class="form-control" name="fill_phone" placeholder="xxx-xxx-xxxx" required>
```

Valid phone numbers should be XXX-XXX-XXXX but it just seems to fail every time. I use the same code on a email field and that will validate just fine.

Comment: not able to replicate. For me it is working as expected

Comment: What does "fail" mean? How does it fail?

Comment: Aside from `emptyField ++` being invalid (you have a space before `++` and even if you didn't, `emptyField` is not declared as a JavaScript tolken), the code works as it should. Voting to close.

Comment: emtyField is not important at this time(i removed it from my code), When I enter a valid number 905-123-1234 the emptyField class still gets added.

Comment: It does not in the code you've shown.

Comment: very strange, am I allowed to post a link to my form?

Comment: Sounds like you need to do some more work to create a [mre]. If you post a link to your form, and someone gives an answer to fix it, you'll fix your form, and the link will no longer make sense or help others with the same problem.

Comment: Not sure why you posted that link after being told not to. The relevant code should exist in the question as per the [mcve] explanation

Comment: The link posted was a very minimal example of my form / page. I had removed about 1000 lines of code from there. Anyways I will remove the link as it did not help me find the solution,

Answer (score 0):

Is the Content being dynamically rendered ? When I was rendering dynamic content I had to change the syntax to get this to work. here is the syntax you can try. if its not static then j query does not find it with the above syntax. this is what worked for me. This tells jquery to check the page for dynamic content.

```
    S(document).on("blur", ".form-control", event => {
  if (!this.validity.valid) {
    $(this).addClass("emptyField");
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass("emptyField");
  }
});
```

Comment: I might still try this as my content was indeed dynamically created. see my above solution,

Comment: It throws an error for me: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'valid' of undefined

Comment: yeah the syntax above will find dynamic rendered content. Not sure where your this.validity is coming from? you could try switching the arrow function to classic function as it binds this to that particular function. Its really hard to say as I can not see the entire project. here is an example   `  
                         $(document).on('blur', ".form", function(){
  //Do Logic Here 
})   Hope it Helps! best of luck. I had a similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

OK, So I figured it out and the problem was caused by something unexpected. The form was being included with php. the form had template variables in it like this, value="{fill_phone}".

Before presenting the form to the visitor the template variables were being replace using str_replace, like this, $form = str_replace('{fill_phone}', '', $form); , I would dynamically run through all the variables on the form.

Once I manually removed all the template variables from the form everything worked fine. I would love for someone to explain this to me as I am to a loss why this would break the form validation. Remember the email validation worked fine but the phone number validation was not working for me.

All is working now. Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score -1):

So you need to use a reg ex with JS or HTML5 Validate Pattern. Let me show you two examples.

## 1

```
     function phonenumber(inputnumber) {
  var phone = /^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/;
  if(inputnumber.value.match(phone)) {
    return true;
  }
  else {
    alert("message");
    return false;
  }
}
```

2. HTML5 Validate

   In HTML5 you can use `<input type='tel'>`

   `<input type='tel'
            pattern='[\+]\d{2}[\(]\d{2}[\)]\d{4}[\-]\d{4}' 
            title='Phone Number 
            (Format: +99(99)9999-9999)'/>`

OR

`<label for="phone">Enter your phone number:</label>`

`<input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone"
       pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}"
       required>`

`<small>Format: 123-456-7890</small>`
`

[Link To MDN HTML5 Phone Input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/tel)

Comment: How does this solve issue when OP is already using pattern attribute?

Comment: The second half of my response was not copied over, See the next answer and it should make sense. If

Comment: Now you are simply guessing which is not how answers should be generated. The code shown in question works. It's up to OP to provide details as to how it doesn't work